# what are siteminder hidden variables and how is data passed to them?

Tags: python, python-requests, siteminder

I am trying to access a Siteminder protected page using Python. Here's what I am doing:

```
import requests
r = requests.session()
postUrl = "http://example.gfm.com:1212/abc.htm"
params = {  'user': 'faisal',
         'password': 'faisal',
             'target': '-SM-http%3a%2f%asdasdasdsad%2efmr%2ecom%3a8081%asdasdasdsad%asdsad%2ehtm',
          'SMENC': 'ISO-8859-1',
          'SMLOCALE': 'US-EN',
          'smauthreason': '0',
          'smquerydata': '',
              'postpreservationdata': ''}
out = r.post(postUrl, data=params, verify=False)
getUrl = "http://status.gfm.com:1212/load.htm"
output = r.get(getUrl, verify=False)
```

I don't know what the hidden variables 'smquerydata' and 'postpreservationdata' are. I read that these variables are defined in the FCC files and are dynamically updated. How are these updated and what are these used for?

Comment: mostly values are somewhere in page code - so you have to GET page, search values and then use them with POST. Better add real url to page.